# Using Connection: Close in webserver SOAP requests

Tags: web-services, wcf, http, soap, .net-4.0

> The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

We're getting this exception frequently when using .Net 4.0 web service client to communicate with an ONVIF network device.

Looking at the [packet captures](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2931731/StackOverflow/23523322/capture1.pcap), this seems to be a device that is non compliant with the HTTP spec and closing a connection after sending the response, against the `HTTP/1.1` default of keeping it alive.
This results in the client (WCF) trying to reuse the connection while the server has just closed it,

Until the manufacturer can fix this, is there any way I can tell the web service/SOAP client NOT to use persistent connections?

Note that modifying the header to use `Connection: Close` won't help unless as it's being closed anyway, but the SOAP client is expecting it to stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying `HttpWebRequest`s are created in the [`HttpChannelFactory`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelFactory.cs#720) used by the generated client classes.
This is created from the [`HttpTransportBindingElement`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpTransportBindingElement.cs#19) which exposes a [`KeepAliveEnabled`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpTransportBindingElement.cs#219) property.

The binding element is created internally in the [`WSHttpBinding`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/WSHttpBindingBase.cs#211) class, and can be changed by overriding [`GetTransport()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/WSHttpBinding.cs#171).

```
private class WSHttpBindingNoKeepAlive : WSHttpBinding {
    public WSHttpBindingNoKeepAlive(SecurityMode securityMode)
        : base(securityMode) {
    }

    protected override TransportBindingElement GetTransport() {
        TransportBindingElement transport = base.GetTransport();
        if (transport is HttpTransportBindingElement) {
            ((HttpTransportBindingElement)transport).KeepAliveEnabled = false;
        }
        return transport;
    }
}
```

This overriden `...Binding` class can then be used like:

```
WSHttpBindingNoKeepAlive clientBinding = new WSHttpBindingNoKeepAlive(SecurityMode.None);
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(this.deviceUrl);
WSNameSpace.WSClient client = new WSNameSpace.WSClient(clientBinding, address);
```

Answer (score 2):

> but is there any way I can tell the web service/SOAP client NOT to use persistent connections?

**Yes**, you can set `InstanceContextMode` to `PerCall`, it will create  new `InstanceContext` object is created prior to and recycled subsequent to each call.

In other words, When we configure a WCF service as per call, new service instances are created for every method call you make via a WCF proxy client.

You can use it like :

- setting in `ServiceBehavior` over Contract Interface implementation like:

  `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
  public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
  {
  ...
  }`

**UPDATE    --**

As per your comment, it seems the solution is to **explicitly set the `KeepAlive` property to `FALSE`**.

It can be done in multiple ways:

1. Code
2. IIS Settings
3. Web.config

**Code**

I actually don't know how much control you have over code.But at the client end where you are consuming service, we can change this behavior like:

```
protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    return webRequest;
}
```

Or

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
    using System;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    /// <summary>
    /// This partial class makes it so all requests specify
    /// "Connection: Close" instead of "Connection: KeepAlive" in the HTTP headers.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class YourServiceNameWse : Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol
    {
        protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
            webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            return webRequest;
        }
    }
}
```

**IIS Settings**

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager:
2. If you are using Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2:

   - On the taskbar, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
   - If you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7:
        On the taskbar, click Start, and then click Control Panel.
   - Double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
   - In the Connections pane, go to the site, application, or directory for which you want to enable HTTP keep-alives.
   - In the Home pane, double-click HTTP Response Headers.
   - In the HTTP Response Headers pane, click Set Common Headers... in the Actions pane.
   - In the Set Common HTTP Response Headers dialog box, uncheck the box to disable HTTP keep-alives, and then click OK.

Additionally you can set for particular website on IIS using **CommandLine** like:

```
appcmd.exe set config "<Your Web Site Here>" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /allowKeepAlive:"False"
```

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="false" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I hope it can help you in some way.

Comment: I don't have control over the server, it's built into the firmware of an IP  connected device. Besides,  it's not an object instancing issue. It's HTTP connection reuse.

Comment: You mean you don't have access to change service code? Besides,  When we configure a WCF service as per call, new service instances are created for every method call you make via a WCF proxy client. So new HTTP connection for each new service request.

Comment: The service implementation is provided by the device manufacturer. It can not be changed without a firmware update from them.

Comment: Yes, it needs to disable the HTTP keep alives to work around the device bug. The code to change the client side may work (I have a similar fix by overriding `WSHttpBinding` to set `KeepAliveEnabled` on the `HttpTransportBindingElement`). The IIS and `Web.Config` dont; apply in this case as the server is not IIS, or even a .Net system.
I'll do more tests when I can.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but our client is not based on `WebServicesClientProtocol`. It's the code generated by Visual Studio that wraps up `ClientBase<>` and the `HttpChannel...` related classes. My solution was to override the binding and set the keepalive there.