# Apache CXF Could not send message caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap, cxf

I am running tomcat server and trying to consume .NET SOAP WS.
Doing that with apache.cxf.

The .NET WS has cluster on it's side, and when restart has performed on one of the machines, I get

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:148)
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

To avoid this, I want to work with connection=close header only for this WS consuming.

So, on creating SOAP messages, I send

```
HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) iMyFlowWSClient.getConduit();
    conduit.getClient().setConnection(ConnectionType.CLOSE);
```

And I see on wireshark that the header get the right value:

```
Connection: close\r\n
```

But, when first call to WS is performed(looks like import of xsd's) on initializating of wsdl url by constractor of java.xml.ws.Service:

```
protected Service(java.net.URL wsdlDocumentLocation, QName serviceName) {
    delegate = Provider.provider().createServiceDelegate(wsdlDocumentLocation,
            serviceName,
            this.getClass());
}
```

I see on Wireshark the next headers:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET /MyFlow.svc?wsdl HTTP/1.1\r\n
    Content-Type: text/xml\r\n
    Accept: */*\r\n
    User-Agent: Apache CXF 3.0.0\r\n
    Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
    Pragma: no-cache\r\n
    Host: 123.123.12.34\r\n
    Connection: keep-alive\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://123.123.12.34/MyFlow.svc?wsdl]
```

And that I believe what keeps alive this connection to WS.

Is there any solution to configure apache.cxf headers to send connection=close on **all** requests that performed on HTTP level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and it looks to me that you will only be able to reduce the problem, not eliminate it. The problem seems to be on the .NET side; closing down the connections is somehow not done right.

Comment: As I wrote, the .NET side have a cluster with several machines, and from time to time they perform a restart to this machines one by one, so the service is always available.
They defined not to use a connection =keep alive for this consuming.

Anyway, it is strange that there is no way to configure the cxf to perform requests with connection=close header.

Comment: I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523322/using-connection-close-in-webserver-soap-requests?rq=1) about this topic, may be helpful in some cases